# How to make MathNet.Numerics work with Unity?

Tags: unity, probability, assembly

[image: Inspector_dll]I have installed the latest version of MathNet on Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager. I've also, copied the `MathNet.Numerics.dll` to an Plugins folder in the Unity editor. Yet it still gives a compiler error: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Distributions' does not exist in the namespace 'MathNet.Numerics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Does anyone know how to solve this or knows a similar package that works with Unity?

Comment: How have you configured the dll import settings in the inspector inside Unity?

Comment: Haven't touched it, kind of a newbie here. Updated question with image.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Specifically curious if this library works in Unity Games deployed to Android or iOS.

Comment: Honestly I don't remember but I don't think I got it working. I think I just used another package, from unity asset store.

Comment: Try put it in Assets/Plugins and then maybe you need to add a reference to it in your asmdef file. I did something like that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to install NuGet packages (and in particular MathNet.Numerics) for Unity using this Plugin: https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity

The instructions are in the repo's README, but the following steps should work:

1. add the NugetForUnity.unitypackage to your Unity Project.
2. Open the NuGet > Manage NuGet Packages Window
3. Search the MathNet.Numerics and install